# How to filter parents by nested objects/arrays values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to allow users to search for nested items using a `searchTerm`.

- The parent array is `departments` which may contain `department` objects.
- Each department object has a `name` key as well as a `roles` array.
- Each `roles` array may contain `employees` and `supervisors` arrays of objects.
- Each `employee` or `supervisor` object contains a `role`, `first_name` and `last_name` key.

The rules are as follows:

- Any `department` which has a `name` key which matches the `searchTerm` should return all nested objects without filtering.
- If there are no departments with `department.name` matching the `searchTerm` then we should filter for any `employee` or `supervisor` object which contains a `role`, `first_name` and `last_name` which includes the `searchTerm`.

**An example departments array**:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "role": "Test 2 Employee",
                        "username": "TestEmployee1",
                        "first_name": "Test2",
                        "last_name": "employee1",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "role": "Test 2 Employee",
                        "username": "TestEmployee2",
                        "first_name": "Test2",
                        "last_name": "Employee2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "role": "Test 2 Employee",
                        "username": "TestEmployee3",
                        "first_name": "Test2",
                        "last_name": "Employee3",
                    },
                ],
                "supervisors": [],
                "employee_type": "Test 2 Employee",
                "group": 2,
                "company": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "employees": [
                    {
                        "id": 26,
                        "role": "Dealer",
                        "username": "Test2Dealer",
                        "first_name": "Test2",
                        "last_name": "Dealer1"
                    }
                ],
                "supervisors": [],
                "employee_type": "Dealer",
                "group": 2,
                "company": 2
            }
        ],
        "created_on": "2022-04-14T16:15:27.299700-07:00",
        "updated_on": "2022-04-17T12:39:36.159563-07:00",
        "name": "Department foo",
        "company": 2
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "roles": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "employees": [],
                "supervisors": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "role": "Test 2 Supervisor",
                        "username": "Test2Super",
                        "first_name": "Test2",
                        "last_name": "Supervsor1",
                    },
                ],
                "employee_type": "Test 2 Supervisor",
                "group": 1,
                "company": 2
            }
        ],
        "created_on": "2022-04-14T16:13:41.769914-07:00",
        "updated_on": "2022-04-14T16:14:05.147650-07:00",
        "name": "Department bar",
        "company": 2
    }
]
```

I currently have it filtering by the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `role` and filtering any roles that don't contain any of these. But I would also like it to return any `department` and all of it's nested objects if the `department.name` contains the `searchTerm`.

**Current filtering logic**:

```
const departments = useSelector((state) => {
    let allDepartments = state.departments;
    if (!searchTerm) {
      return allDepartments;
    }
    // if the searchTerm exists in any department.name, employee.role,
    // employee.first_name, employee.last_name, supervisor.first_name,
    // supervisor.last_name, or supervisor.role, then return that department
    const filteredDepartments = allDepartments.departments
      .map((department) => ({
        ...department,
        roles: department.roles.map((role) => {
          return {
            ...role,
            employees: role.employees.filter((employee) => {
              return (
                employee.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                employee.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                employee.role.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
              );
            }),
          };
        }),
      }))
      .map((department) => ({
        ...department,
        roles: department.roles
          .map((role) => {
            return {
              ...role,
              supervisors: role.supervisors.filter((supervisor) => {
                return (
                  supervisor.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                  supervisor.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
                  supervisor.role.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                );
              }),
            };
          })
          .filter(
            (role) => role.supervisors.length > 0 || role.employees.length > 0
          ),
      }))
      .filter(
        (department) =>
          department.roles.length > 0 ||
          // department.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) this doesn't work because it has already filtered out the employees and supervisors which do not match.
      );

    const newDepartments = { ...allDepartments };
    newDepartments.departments = filteredDepartments;
    return newDepartments;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out (no thanks to the person who marked this as 'close' because it needs more focus). GitHub CoPilot was able to fill in the code I needed after I wrote the steps in comments.

I felt I needed to add a second filtering function, which filters all the departments by `department.name`:

```
  const filteredByDepartmentName = allDepartments.departments.filter(
    (department) =>
      department.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );
```

Then I need to check to see if the department already exists in the final array. If it does exist then I should replace it with the department in `filteredByDepartmentName`. If it does not exist then I should `.push()` it into the final array:

```
  newDepartments.departments = filteredByEmployee;
  // Check if the departments in filteredByDepartmentName already exist in 
  // newDepartments.departments. If they do, replace the old department with 
  // the new one. If they dont, add the new department to 
  // newDepartments.departments

  filteredByDepartmentName.forEach((department) => {
    const index = newDepartments.departments.findIndex(
      (newDepartment) => newDepartment.id === department.id
    );
    if (index === -1) {
      newDepartments.departments.push(department);
    } else {
      newDepartments.departments[index] = department;
    }
  });

  return newDepartments;
```